# Python idle won't start on windows

Tags: python, python-idle

"IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess of personal firewall software is blocking the connection."

My python idle always says that so I cant do my work my pc is 32 bits on windows 10 hp brobook 4540s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326291/idle-subprocess-startup-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says your firewall is blocking it. You need to add an exception to the firewall settings.

Comment: thanks champ the solution works

Comment: After adding an exception to the firewall it worked but now it's back again help please